# View All Site Content Link goes to Content of Incorrect Site

Tags: administration, alternate-access-mapping, windows-authentication

Can you explain why a View All Site Content link would go to the wrong place? I've never seen this before, but a friend reports it happening on a test farm. What could explain most everything else working but the View All Site Content link.

Details:
A new Windows Server 2008 R2 web server was added to the farm. The previous web server was Windows Server 2003. This is SharePoint 2007 SP2+. After applying the SSL cert and changing the bindings manually in IIS, the admin reports that the URL was mangled and the View All Site Content link on all sub-sites goes to the content for the root site. This is a site collection that is accessible through two different addresses and authentication methods, forms and windows.

Comment: Does the View All Site Content Link point to wrong destination to begin with, or is it pointing to correct URL, but user gets redirected from thet URL to wrong location?

Comment: I've got this happening right now on a production farm.  I did alter the master page slightly (very minor change in to link the subsites back to the main site) so I'm going to try change that back to how it was. The only other thing was we did change the default AAMs for the site.

Comment: We have the same issue on SharePoint 2010. On hovering and clicking the URL in browser is correct i.e http://sitecollection/subiste/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx? but the content of the page is of root site only. Any idea on how to fix the issue?

Comment: As far as I know, this was related to the session state setting in the web.config file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A web.config setting was found to be responsible for this case.

I don't have the full details, but apparently changing the session state from InProc to SQLServer solved the problem.

You can read more about using ASP.Net Session State with SharePoint here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I am interested in what the link shows as it's target when hovering over it. Looking at the v4.master, the link uses the ~site placeholder so it should be pointing to the current subweb's root. And neither the viewlsts.aspx or it's codebehind seem to have any redirect code in it...

Comment: Can't tell you. I was not hands on for this issue, but it sounded unique enough, I thought this might be a good forum for it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem for a customer. Your comment also stated the cause of the problem, manually changing bindings in IIS. THe AAM must be configured to correctly match the request headers.

"After applying the SSL cert and changing the bindings manually in IIS, the admin reports that the URL was mangled and the View All Site Content link on all sub-sites goes to the content for the root site."